# Re-encoding Motion JPG AVI to XVid efficiently

Tags: windows, avi, video-encoding, xvid

I have several devices that record motion jpg video.

These are large.

I want to re-encode to Xvid AVI files using Virtualdub, however, the default settings for the XVid codec end up with a file the same size. Which is no good.

Can anyone point me at some appropriate settings to get a smaller file at reasonable quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm) for batch conversions. You can have some encoding profiles there for various devices. I can give you more detailed encoding info and I can also send you my encoding profile.

I you could tell us, what parameters the video has - which resolution and better a [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) text dump for some example file. Because the video from various devices can have very variable parameters.